Browser allways pull old static files
I have a Reactjs app. When build production, I deleted wwwroot folder, then create again and copy all built file into that folder (css and js file name are always different). When i reload website, the browser always pulls the old js, css files, unless I refresh with Ctrl+F5.
Build, deploy and reload website

Your server probably sets aggressive caching headers. The browser is simply doing what it's instructed (retain cache for a set amount of time). To change this, either make sure your filenames are different for every deploy or update your server settings to cache for a shorter time.
